# Call the JavaScript function from Code Behind with Parameter

Tags: c#, javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(a)
    {

        window.opener.document.forms[0].elements['src'].value = a;
    }
  </script>




protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(this.fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);
        fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
        ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + filename;
        btnUpload.OnClientClick = string.Format("test(\'{0}\');",ImageUrl);
        Response.Write("<script language="'javascript'"> {top.close() }</script>");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I nedd to call the javascript function named test with parameter

i am trying like above but its not working plz help me thanx in advance

Comment: What html code is rendered in the client for the button?

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" style="height: 26px" Width="80px"  />

Comment: Try btnUpload.OnClientClick = string.Format("test('{0}');",ImageUrl); and pull this code line out of btnUpload_Click method to a page_load method.

Comment: yes it is working but with manual parameter not dynamic like
btnUpload.OnClientClick = string.Format("test('someParam');");
it is working perfectly

Comment: Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> {window.opener.document.forms[0].elements['src'].value = '"+ImageUrl+"'; top.close();}</script>");


Resolved...............Thanx All